# Including custom holiday definition lists in Holidays gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone help me out with including custom holiday definition lists into the Ruby holidays gem?

I have not been able to figure anything out.

I have no example code since looking at the Gem is all I can recommend.

**edit**:

I am looking to use this gem to create a UI in an app to allow a user to define a holiday. The YAML would be stored most likely in the DB. I need to be able to tap in to the rake task in the gem and run it dynamically. I am not totally aware of how to reach into the gems rake task from within my rails app.

Comment: Isn't `merge_defs` responsible for loading up new holidays?